# Display emoij on webpage

Tags: java, html, character-encoding

When a user enters an message like this: "||"
The form converts it to `"%7C%F0%9F%98%98%7C"` and
that gets stored in the db.
Now I would like to to have it display in this format:

```
"|&#....;|"
```

How could I achieve this?

I have already tried this:

```
    String utf16 = URLDecoder.decode(message, "utf-8");
    return HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(message, "utf-16");
```

But this displays `"|?|"` on the webpage.